# List all combinations

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have a list [1, 2, 3].
I want a function that takes in the list and another number, the length.

```
f([1, 2, 3], 4) = [
[1, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 1 , 1, 2],
[1, 1, 1, 3],
[1, 1, 2, 1],
[1, 1, 3, 1],
#and so on...
]
```

Maybe itertools has an answer?

Comment: You can check it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864/python-code-to-pick-out-all-possible-combinations-from-a-list

Comment: "maybe itertools has an answer" have you even spent some time checking itertools?

Comment: Can you be more specific in your requirement? Should two items in the result be included if they have the same elements in a different order? Is the next item `[1,1,2,1]` or `[1,1,2,2]`? In total, does the result have 15 items or 81?

Comment: Sorry for the unclear post

Comment: The intended result should contain 81.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`itertools.combinations_with_replacement`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement) is the function you seek.

```
In [17]: i=itertools.combinations_with_replacement((1,2,3), 4)

In [18]: next(i)
Out[18]: (1, 1, 1, 1)

In [19]: next(i)
Out[19]: (1, 1, 1, 2)

In [20]: next(i)
Out[20]: (1, 1, 1, 3)

In [21]: next(i)
Out[21]: (1, 1, 2, 2)

In [22]:
```

If you want the set of all combinations, including items which differ only in order, try this:

```
# Modified from itertools.combinations_with_replace example
# from the python doc.
import itertools
import pprint
def odometer(iterable, r):
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    for indices in itertools.product(range(n), repeat=r):
        yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)

pprint.pprint (list(odometer([1,2,3], 4)))
```

Comment: Is there a possible way to get all the possibilities in one list?

Comment: Yes, `l=list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement((1,2,3), 4))`